# Aggregates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-aggregate

Write an aggregate to count the number of times the number 40 is seen in a column.

Use your aggregate to count the number of 40 year olds in the directory table.

This is what I was doing:

```
Create function aggstep(curr int) returns int as $$
begin
    return curr.count where age = 40;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

Create aggregate aggs(integer) (
stype = int,
initcond = '',
sfunc = aggstep);

Select cas(age) from directory;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it for example like this:

First, create a transition function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count40func(bigint, integer) RETURNS bigint
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT AS
'SELECT $1 + ($2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 40)::integer::bigint';
```

That works because `FALSE::integer` is 0 and `TRUE::integer` is 1.

I use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` rather than `=` so that it does the correct thing for NULLs.

The aggregate can then be defined as

```
CREATE AGGREGATE count40(integer) (
   SFUNC = count40func,
   STYPE = bigint,
   INITCOND = 0
);
```

You can then query like

```
SELECT count40(age) FROM directory;
```

Comment: That's surprising - unless I'm completely wrong, this should solve your homework question.

Comment: It actually asks to create aggregate and use it to find number of 40 year olds from table..considering we have table with column age

Comment: Oh, I thought that was obvious - I have added a line to the answer.

Comment: thank you very much, actually I looked back into your solution and it did work, really appreciate your help. Ok, I will start looking into documentation again, I have already gone through it but now will pay more attention

Comment: I am glad to hear that - I thought it could only be a misunderstanding.

Comment: could you please tell me why do we enter bigint and int here: 

CREATE FUNCTION count40func(bigint, integer) RETURNS bigint

while input is age which is int? What is the significance? It will really help me understand it once for all

Comment: That is just in expectation that counts can potentially be very large. `count` returns `bigint` too. But for the example here you can use `integer` just as well.